# maximum column count in specific row

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to know the number of used (non-empty) columns in a specific row, let's say row no 4.

```
len(sheet[4])
```

gives me the number of columns used in total, not just of the 4th row

```
sheet[4].max_column
```

doesn't work.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `.max_column` is a function of the sheet, not the row. try `print(sheet.max_column)`. Where as you should be able to just do `print(len(sheet[4]))` for instance. IIRC each row is a list of the different columns?

Comment: Sorry, I asked quite misleadingly. I do not need the maximum number of columns in total, but only for the 4th row.  print(len(sheet[4]))  shows the total maximum of columns.

Answer (score 0):

You should really think of a spreadsheet as always being 16,384 columns and 1,000,000 rows. Anything else is essentially dependent upon implementation specifics.

If you follow this logic through then you can find the highest row in any particular column by counting down from `ws.max_column` to the first non-empty cell. You can do this with column indexing:

```
for cell in reversed(ws[4]):
     if cell.value is not None:
         break

print("max row for column {0} is {1}".format(cell.col_idx, cell.row)
```